# Second container does not load jquery masonry in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry

I am trying to display my posts organized by date created. Jquery Masonry works fine for the first container, but for the second container it fails to properly load. When I view the code in a web browser it shows this for the second container:

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
      <div class="box panel panel-default">

      </div>
  </div>
```

when it should show this (content display for the first container):

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled masonry" style="position: relative; height: 247px; width: 448px;">
      <div class="box panel panel-default masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

      </div>

  </div>
```

app/assets/javascripts/pin.js.coffee:

```
$ -> 
$('#pins').imagesLoaded ->
$('#pins').masonry
  itemSelector: '.box'
  isFitWidth: true
```

views/pins/index.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'pages/home' %>

<div id="pins-container" class="container">
 <% @pins_by_day.each do |day, pins| %>
   <h5 align="center"> <%= day.strftime('%B %d, %Y') %> </h5>
    <div class="well well-sm">
     <div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
      <% for pin in pins %>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
         <%= link_to pin %>

          <div class="panel-body">
            <p>
              <%= pin.description %>
            </p>
          </div>

      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to properly load jquery masonry for multiple containers on my page. The first section is loading properly, but the second container is just a single column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML doesn't like it when you have more than one id per page. And jQuery will only find the first one. So if you're ever iterating over a partial or a template, make sure that you either don't use ids, or have the id be dynamic.

So instead of `id="pins"` try:

```
<div class="masonry-pins transitions-enabled">
```

And

```
$ -> 
  $('.masonry-pins').imagesLoaded ->
    $('.masonry-pins').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

Also, I imagine inside `imagesLoaded` callback, you have access to the element at `this`? Instead of calling `$('.masonry-pins').masonry` you might just want to call `$(this).masonry`

Comment: Awesome explanation - your fix worked perfectly. Thanks for the help